# reading file and splitting the data from a file based on pattern in shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a big file name lef_list with data in below format:

```
$PRJ/fp/t/std/tcb/libs/tcb.lb.gz \
$PRJ/mm/T/v/mem_gen/ram/NLDM/ram.lib \
```

I want to read each line of file and split the lines into two based on pattern '/libs/' or '/NLDM/' in line and replace those with word '/LEF/' and write in a new file.

The output should be like :

```
$PRJ/fp/t/std/tcb/lef/tcb.lb.gz \
$PRJ/mm/T/v/mem_gen/ram/LEF/ram.lib \
```

I tried the below code:

```
while IFS="/libs/" read -r line val
do 
   echo "$line"/LEF/"$val"; 
done < lef_list
```

This code shows error as while expression syntax. command not found.

Someone please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `sed` should do the job:

```bash
sed -E 's~/(libs|NLDM)/~/LEF/~g' file

$PRJ_WORK_DIR/foundationip/tsmc/tsmc_lvt_stdcells/tcbn16ffcllbwp16p90cpdlvt/LEF/ccs/tcbn16ffcllbwp16p90cpdlvtssgnp0p72vm40c_hm_ccs.lib.gz \
$PRJ_WORK_DIR/mem/tech/TSMC_16FFC/v37/mem_gen/data_new/ram_dp_ulvt_pg_rd_64x44_mux4/LEF/ram_dp_ulvt_pg_rd_64x44_mux4_ssgnp0p72vm40c.lib \
```

Pattern `/(libs|NLDM)/` matches `/libs/` or `/NLDM/` and replaces that with `/LEF/`.

Or if you have to use `awk` only then:

```bash
awk '{gsub(/\/(libs|NLDM)\//, "/LEF/")} 1' file
```

Comment: If I want to replace based on pattern in line, like if mem_gen in line, I want to replace /NLDM/ with /LEF/ and rest with /lef/?

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY: That would be: `sed  '/\/mem_gen\// s~/NLDM/~/LEF/~g; s~/libs/~/lef/~g' file`

Comment: If I have a data, i want to search for mem_gen in line and if found replace /NLDM/ with /LEF/ and output only the first part of data till /LEF/

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY: Not a good idea to keep asking new questions from comments. I have answered one additional problem from comments but usually it is one problem per post on SO

Comment: Last problem's solution: `sed -E '/\/mem_gen\// s~(.*)/NLDM/.*~\1/LEF/~g; s~(.*)/libs/.*~\1/lef/~g' file`